# "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property" when rendering Expressjs view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am building an app in node.js and encountered an error when I tried to send data from my server to my view:

```
module.exports = function (req, res) {

var cookie = parseCookie.parseCookie(req.headers.cookie);

user.returnUser(cookie, function(result) {

    var context = result[0].first_name;
    console.log(context); //console logs properly
    res.render('../views/home', context); //errors out at 'context'
});
};
```

The error returned is:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_locals' of Josh
at ServerResponse.render (/Users/tinzors/Documents/portal/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:952:16)
at /Users/tinzors/Documents/portal/controllers/home.js:27:7
at /Users/tinzors/Documents/portal/methods/returnUser.js:8:5
at tryCatcher (/Users/tinzors/Documents/portal/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/tinzors/Documents/portal/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:507:31)
at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/Users/tinzors/Documents/portal/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:581:18)
at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/tinzors/Documents/portal/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:697:14)
at Async._drainQueue (/Users/tinzors/Documents/portal/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:123:16)
at Async._drainQueues (/Users/tinzors/Documents/portal/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:133:10)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/tinzors/Documents/portal/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:374:17)
```

My view:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

{{> header}}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/home.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
      <h1>Welcome home, {{first_name}}.</h1>
    </div>
</html>
```

I'm not sure if it helps, but `user.returnUser` calls a method that returns data from a DB query.

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: i just updated my question w/ my view code @user2864740

Comment: Ah.. I suspect the desired outcome can be obtained with `context = {first_name: result[0].first_name}` or even `context = result[0]`. It is probably an error to use a string as the template context, although if that is the case one would need to dig deeper into the implementation. Also, check that the results are as expected.

Comment: that works!!! @user2864740